# sklearn models Parameter tuning GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, gridsearchcv

Dataframe:

```
id    review                                              name         label
1     it is a great product for turning lights on.        Ashley       1
2     plays music and have a good sound.                  Alex         1
3     I love it, lots of fun.                             Peter        0
```

The aim is to classify the text; if the review is about the functionality of the product (e.g. turn the light on, music), `label=1`, otherwise `label=0`.

I am running several sklearn models to see which one works bests:

```
# Naïve Bayes:
text_clf_nb = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

# Linear Support Vectors Classifier:
text_clf_lsvc = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', LinearSVC(loss='hinge',
              penalty='l2', max_iter = 50))])

# SGDClassifier
text_clf_sgd = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3,                                                    random_state=42,max_iter=50, tol=None))])

#Random Forest
text_clf_rf = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])

#neural network MLPClassifier
text_clf_mlp = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', MLPClassifier())])
```

**Problem**: How to tune models using GridSearchCV? What I have so far:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),'clf__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3) }
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf_nb, param_grid= parameters, cv=2,  scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit((X_train, y_train))
```

This gives the following error on running `gs_clf = gs_clf.fit((X_train, y_train))`:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('tfidf',
                 TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False,
                                 decode_error='strict',
                                 dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>,
                                 encoding='utf-8', input='content',
                                 lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None,
                                 min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l2',
                                 preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
                                 stop_words=None, strip_accents=None,
                                 sublinear_tf=False,
                                 token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
                                 tokenizer=None, use_idf=True,
                                 vocabulary=None)),
                ('clf',
                 MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True))],
         verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Following the error message's advice, run `gs_clf.get_params().keys()`.  It looks like your provided error message is not the one that should've come out of the code you provided, but maybe from a different classifier?

Comment: @BenReiniger it gives me the following:    dict_keys(['cv', 'error_score', 'estimator__memory', 'estimator__steps', 'estimator__verbose',...]

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should've said `text_clf_nb.get_params().keys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of calling the parameters inside `Pipeline` is using double underscore like `named_step__parameter_name` .So the first thing I noticed is in this line:

```
parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),'clf__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3) }
```

You are calling `vect__ngram_range` but this should be `tfidf__ngram_range`

Now this is no the error displayed, rather it seems as if you were somewhere mixed your code since `C` is a parameter for an SVM not for a MultinomialNB, so check if you are really passing the intended pipeline since I suspect that you are passing the `pipeline` that constants the SVM but trying to hyper parametrize the `MultinomialNB`

So check if this dictionary:

```
parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),'clf__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3) }
```

is being also created but for an SVM (the two with the same name `parameter`)

Finally I would also change those lines:

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf_nb, param_grid= parameters, cv=2,  scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit((X_train, y_train))
```

for only this:

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf_nb, param_grid= parameters, cv=2,  scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It is confusing why you are passing a tuple to the fit method.